# Can someone see why this JQuery JSONP is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, jsonp

```
$.getJSON("https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?&callback=fs_venue_search", {
        ll: "40.7,-74",       
        client_id: "Y3AWKSPSCWEGGSQBELQVDWRG4EX4PRWJ4HMWSKGQSVRPPXI1",
        client_secret: "abc",

        format: "json"
    }, function(data){
        alert(data);
    });
```

Nothing happens when I run this script.

Comment: stab in the dark: `callback` is in the url and json parameters with different values?

Comment: I don't know that it matters, but your callback function is spelled differently in the URL ("fs_venure_search") than it is in the argument block ("fs_venue_search").

Comment: Regardless of spelling and moving that around it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

```
$.getJSON("https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search", {
        ll: "40.7,-74",       
        client_id: "Y3AWKSPSCWEGGSQBELQVDWRG4EX4PRWJ4HMWSKGQSVRPPXI1",
        client_secret: "abc",
        format: "jsonp"
    }, function(data){
        alert(data);
    });
```

Comment: It is strange that you have already a working solution 10 minutes after you asked it. If you already have the solution, do not spend other people's time to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

This one

```
$.getJSON("https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?&callback=?", {
    ll: "40.7,-74",
    client_id: "Y3AWKSPSCWEGGSQBELQVDWRG4EX4PRWJ4HMWSKGQSVRPPXI1",
    client_secret: "5FBPDNM2TQDMFSBQUKZSWR3ZGJWDTXYA2IHJLLMMO0J2LVC",

    format: "json"
}, function(data){
    alert(data.meta.code);
});
```

work and display "200".

Answer (score 0):

You're providing `callback=` in the original URL and in the data object. One of them appears to be misspelt.  Set only one, and see if your code then works.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I retyped the spelling and also moved stuff around to only one of them.